# android know if an app is installed

Tags: android

Hello is it possible to know if the user tries to uninstall an application and ask for password in order to continue? I have a security application and I would like to ask the user to authenticate before uninstalling the application is it possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hello is it possible to know if the user tries to uninstall an application and ask for password in order to continue?

No, sorry. Applications do not get control when they get uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. I do not know **HOW** but some security applications like AndroidLost, SeekDroid and so on do that. (I'm not sure now which one exactly do that, but I'm sure it does). Try to decompile some of these applications (if I was you I'd do that).

I guess they ask for Administration permission in your mobile and intercept the unnistall. Obviously if you remove the app from the Administration apps list, it does not work anymore.